# How to implement many-to-many relationship in ScriptDB

Tags: google-apps-script

For example if I want to store which cities persons have visited then each city would have multiple visitors and each person will visit more than once city, how should I implement that?

Sometimes I want to query on city attributes (for example all persons that visited a city in France), and other times I might want to query on person attributes (all cities visited by people younger than 30).

I have thought of two ways myself:

1. Include an array of visitors in each city object, and an array of cities in each person object. However, this means storing the same data twice and it might make the objects big.
2. Create an extra object 'visit' storing the ID of both a city and a person.

Option two seems best to me. However, I think it would take at least three ScriptDB queries for each of the two query examples. Also the 'anyOf' would become quite large, and I'm not sure if that is a problem.

Example:

```
var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();

var cityResult = db.query({type: 'city', country: 'France'});
var citiesInFrance= getAllCityIds(cityResult);

var visitResult = db.query({type: 'visit', cityId: db.anyOf(citiesInFrance)});
var personsVisitedFrance = getAllPersonIds(visitResult);

var personResult = db.query({type: 'person', personId: db.anyOf(personsVisitedFrance)});
```

This seems somewhat cumbersome, especially when compared to an oldskool sql query. Is this the way to go, or should I look into something else altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it all depends on what you want to optimize. What you do more often: register a visit or query visitors?

On "oldskool" sql the rule is to "normalize" data, that means you should really store the visits separately and complicate your query. But on no-sql, people usually go with the first option. Making query easy and changes a little more complicated. Which is what I'd do myself. It's the trade off between speed and space.

Just a note, on ScriptDb you're not able to [query if an item is inside an array](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1733). So you really need to set a "map" of visited cities and/or countries. e.g.

```
person = {type:'person', personId:'foo', otherFields:'bar',
   visitedCities:{Paris:true, Nantes:true}, visitedCountries:{France:true}};
```

And something similar for the cities if you need to query in them. If you need just the listing, than an array is probably more appropriate.